# Oracle date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: oracle, date, time

My table has two DATE format attributes, however, when i try to insert value it throws an error: **date format picture ends before converting entire input string.**
Here is my attempted code:

```
insert into visit
values(123456, '19-JUN-13', '13-AUG-13 12:56 A.M.');
```

I think the problem is with `12:56` but Oracle documentation says `date` implies both date and time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Perhaps you should check `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and use the date string conforming the format.
Or you can use `to_date` function within the `INSERT` statement, like the following:

```
insert into visit
values(123456, 
       to_date('19-JUN-13', 'dd-mon-yy'),
       to_date('13-AUG-13 12:56 A.M.', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi A.M.'));
```

Additionally, Oracle `DATE` stores **date** and **time** information together.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i tried `to_date`, but i have an error on the 3rd line where `to_date` starts: `date format not recognized`

Comment: @Buras Oops, there was a typo. I modified `mmm` to `mon`.

Comment: Thank you very much. May i ask a question, i used to insert dates without this part: `dd-mon-yy`...  simply: '19-JUN-13'. Why doesn't it work in Oracle. Do i always have to specify the `dd-mon...` things?

Comment: @Buras Perhaps it is due to the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter which specifies the default format of `DATE`. You should check the parameter.

Answer (score 14):

you need to alter session

you can try before insert

```
 sql : alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to insert is not a date, I think, but a string. You need to use `to_date()` function, like this:

```
insert into table t1 (id, date_field) values (1, to_date('20.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this error today and discovered it was an incorrectly-formatted year...

```
select * from es_timeexpense where parsedate > to_date('12/3/2018', 'MM/dd/yyy')
```

Notice the year has only three 'y's. It should have 4.

Double-check your format.

Comment: Just now had the same error, same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the query for the conversion was present in a subquery.
while executing the subquery, it gave excellent results and while doing complete query it failed to execute.

So what I did was to remove all other conditions like the null check and length check to the main query and the subquery had only the date conversion based filter.

Hope it helps