# i am getting an error" not valid month"

Tags: date, database-design, oracle11g, format

```
create table Department
(Dname varchar(255) NOT NULL, Dnumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Mgr_SSN char(9) NOT NULL, Mgr_start_Date DATE);

insert into Department values('HR', '1', '11001', '2012-04-05 10:15:00');
```

I am getting the error `"not valid month"`.
Should we define date format when we create the table?
I am using `Oracle11g`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206160/oracle-how-to-use-time-and-date)

Answer (score 2):

When you have a `DATE` column, you should always insert a `DATE`, not a `VARCHAR2`.  Relying on implicit casting to correctly convert the string is a bad idea-- it is very easy for different sessions to have different NLS settings and, thus, to do the implicit conversion differently (either resulting in a different `DATE` or an error).  The easiest way to do that is to use the `to_date` function.

```
insert into Department( dname, 
                        dnumber,
                        mgr_ssn,
                        mgr_start_date )
  values('HR', 
         1, 
         '11001', 
         to_date( '2012-04-05 10:15:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') );
```

I also modified the statement to list the columns, which is generally a good practice since it ensures that you don't have to look up the physical order of columns in the table every time and since it allows the `INSERT` statement to work in the future if you add new columns to the table.  Since `dnumber` is a `NUMBER`, I also changed the `INSERT` statement to insert a number rather than inserting a string (again, don't rely on implicit conversion if there is no need to do so).  I did not correct the apparent bug that you have a `CHAR(9)` column representing a social security number for which you are inserting a 5 character string.