# SQL SELECT date from table, and calculate how many days since that date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datediff, days

I'm looking to calculate how many days have passed since a specific date, retrieved from a table in my database. Based on the info I've found on W3Schools ([Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)), I have attempted using DATEDIFF, but am coming up against a couple of different errors I can't seem to work around.

I have included my code below, and based on this, what I want to happen is this: Select the "DD" from the "Wave_Data" table, and, based on "sysdate", work out how many days have lapsed since then.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEKDAY,:P1_DD,SYSDATE)
FROM WAVE_DATA
WHERE WAVE_NUMBER = :P1_WAVE;
```

The final calculation would then be inputted into a text field within my ApEx database.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide,

Dominic

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: A couple of different ones, but the most recent/current error is: Failed to parse SQL query!
ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier

Comment: If this is Oracle, which it looks like, you can subtract dates.  Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406397/datediff-function-in-oracle)

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: DATEDIFF is not a valid Oracle function

Comment: @Hashman, I've followed the instructions from this link. New script looks like this:

SELECT TO_DATE(:P1_DD, 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
       TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM   WAVE_DATA
WHERE WAVE_NUMBER = :P1_WAVE;

after this change, though, I receive this error: Oracle date format picture ends before converting entire input string. Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206160/oracle-date-format-picture-ends-before-converting-entire-input-string) link, it might have something to do with the format of the dates. Any ideas?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm running Oracle ApEx 4.1

Comment: @Sparky Do you know of any Oracle alternatives to this? Potentially what Hashman suggested?

Comment: It would help if you posted sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you can just subtract one Date from another to get the difference (in days) between them:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - :p1_dd
FROM   Wave_Data
WHERE  Wave_Number = :p1_wave;
```

If you want to know the difference between the dates without any time parts then you can do:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( :p1_dd )
FROM   Wave_Data
WHERE  Wave_Number = :p1_wave;
```

or

```
SELECT FLOOR( SYSDATE - :p1_dd )
FROM   Wave_Data
WHERE  Wave_Number = :p1_wave;
```

Comment: Should that be sysdate - :p1_dd?

Comment: This works (almost) perfectly! I added a "TO_DATE" in there, and I'm good to go! Additionally, is there any way to say "Only do this if P1_DD is in the past"? Might be pushing the friendship, though!

Comment: `CASE WHEN :p1_dd < SYSDATE THEN SYSDATE - :p1_dd END` will get the difference if it is in the past or `NULL` otherwise.